# Not executing the code outside of the while loop after the break statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to exit an infinite loop but I'm stuck in it. I've tried using the break statement in different ways but the result is always the same: the program terminates after exiting the loop and it doesn't perform the rest of the code. What should I change in the code to solve this problem?

```
moylist = []
import copy
while True:
    thing = input()
    if thing == '':
      break
    moylist.append(thing)
moylist.insert(-2, 'and')
moynovlist = copy.deepcopy(moylist)
moynovlist1 = moynovlist[-2:] # cutting the end
perv = str(moynovlist1)
perv1 = perv[:4] + perv[4:] #without the comma (and ...)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. I'm voting to close this question as "not reproducible", based on [Zachary's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63441369/4518341) and my own testing. In the future, you need to make a [mre] to narrow down what the problem is. See [ask] if you want more advice. BTW, "stuck in infinite loop" and "program terminates" are incompatible. Your loop is only infinite if the break-condition is never met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is running fine! The reason you think it is exiting the whole program instead of just the while loop is because you don't have any print statements. Simply add, `print(perv1)` at the end of your program and you'll see that `perv1` changes, meaning the loop was exited properly.